# Kubuntu networking configuration file

Tags: networking, kubuntu, files, configuration

I've always been a GTK camp user but switched to Kubuntu just recently (for 20.04). But I haven't found where Kubuntu store its networking configuration files yet. I've looked at every file that I know of, e.g.:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ dir /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
total 0

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

The reason I'm asking is that I want to use Static IP for my Kubuntu, but I don't know where do I start with. thx.

Comment: NetworkManager stores it's config in the same place under both KDE and Gnome. The easy way to set up static IP is to use the NM GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer directly updating configuration file on command line, and I thought NetworkManager stores it's config files under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.

Comment: Are you willing to use `nmcli` instead of mucking about with config files?

Comment: Sure, if you think it is better than the latter, @user535733

Comment: Assigning static IP address using nmcli: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/assigning-static-ip-address-using-nmcli

Comment: Thanks @user535733!